# Estimator errors in Adaboost sklearn python

Tags: python, ensemble-learning

I was implementing sklearn AdaBoostClassifier and I plotted the estimator_errors_ which said is the classification error for each estimator in the boosted ensemble.

This is the plot:

[image]

I have few questions:
1. is it the errors for the test set or train set?
2. why in 30 the error is 1?
3. is it accumulated error?

Thank you.

my code:

```
base = LinearSVC(tol=1e-10, loss='hinge', C=1000, max_iter=50000)
ada = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=base ,algorithm='SAMME', n_estimators=n,random_state=10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sklearn AdaBoostClassifier has a default parameter for n_estimators=50 which I believe is used in your case. However, the boosting process may terminate early if one of the other conditions is reached. This maybe dictated by one of the stopping conditions for the base estimator or the SAMME algorithm.

In your case based on the plot, it seems like the boosting stops after 30 estimators. You can easily obtain the actual number of estimators using,

```
len(estimator)
```

where estimator is the fitted estimator using AdaBoostClassifier. The type of error depends on the function performed before printing `estimator_errors_`.

```
estimator.predict(X_test) 
estimator.estimator_errors_
```

shows error for the test data `X_test`.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use the default parameter for n_estimators but I think in that case it is n=50. I wanted to know the optimal number of estimators, so before the error is 1 it is the optimal? why is it 100% error? "..other conditions is reached" whats kind of condition? the results isnt that good..

Comment: The error plot shows 1 because usually that estimator was never trained and also the same reason shows a 100% error. Did you check len(estimator)? Is it 30 or 50? Also at what point are you getting estimator_errors_? after calling predict in your estimator? Would be good if you can expand your code to show these.